# How to show error message with jquery tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am validating my controls in a form... if a control is empty i would like to show a jquery tooltip with that error msg.. Here is what i am doing...

```
if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListDiscipline")
    .selectedIndex == -1) 
{
  document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ErrorMsg").innerHTML = 
      "please select your Discipline";
  document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListDiscipline").focus();
  return false;
}
```

and i would like to do like this,

```
if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListDiscipline")
    .selectedIndex == -1) 
{
  // show tooltip besides the control with the error message...
  document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListDiscipline").focus();
  return false;
}
```

Any suggestion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-jquery-plugins-to-create-an-user-friendly-tooltip/) you will find some useful plugins to make tooltips with jQuery

For example with [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) installed you can do something like this:

```
if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListDiscipline")
.selectedIndex == -1) 
{
  $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListDiscipline').qtip(
  {
    content: "please select your Discipline"
  });
  document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ListDiscipline").focus();
  return false;
}
```